# find common tangent between curves $y=x^3$ and $112x^2 +y^2 =112$

Tags: derivatives, conic-sections, tangent-line

Find common tangent between curves $y=x^3$ and $112x^2 +y^2 =112$

For common tangent slope of both the curve must be equal and then we have to find the point of intersection of the curves.

Problem is that I can't able to find the point of intersection of the curves.

Comment: Two curves can have common tangents without ever intersecting. The same line can be tangent to both graphs without being tangent to the graphs _at the same point_. For instance, $y = x^2$ and $y = -(x-1)^2$ have the $x$-axis as a common tangent (they have one more common tangent as well, but that one is not as obvious).

Comment: So how can I solve this question without finding point of intersection

Comment: Points of intersection between the two curves are basically of no interest to finding common tangents. Some times curves are tangent, and in that case, yes, that point will give you a common tangent. But unless specifically engineered to do so, it will take a major coincidence.

Comment: I would suggest writing the equations of the tangent lines to each curve. Then try to find the slope(s) for which the tangent lines to the two curves with that slope have the same y-intercept (or x-intercept if more convenient).

Comment: Another approach would be to figure out which tangents to the cubic curve intersect the ellipse at exactly one point.

Comment: As noted in the comments above, the points of intersection are not relevant to the question, but they are the simultaneous solutions to $y=x^3$ and $112x^2+y^2=112$, hence to
$$x^6+112x^2-112=0.$$
This is a cubic in $x^2$ with a unique real solution because its discriminant
$$\Delta=-4\times112^3-27\times112^2,$$
is negative. Cardano's formula then gives an explicit expression for $x^2$, and this yields expressions for the two points of intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=mx+n$ is a tangent to ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ iff $n^2=a^2m^2+b^2$.

Let $(t,t^3)$ is touching point of the tangent to the graph of $y=x^3$.

Thus, $y-t^3=3t^2(x-t)$ or $y=3t^2x-2t^3$ is an equation of the common tangent.

Thus, $$(-2t^3)^2=1\cdot(3t^2)^2+112.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 2):

The tangent of $y=x^3$ at $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$ 
y= 3 x_0 ^2 x - 2 x_0 ^3 \tag1
$$
the tangent of $ 112 x^2 + y^2 = 112$ at $(x_1, y_1)$:
$$
112 x_1 x + y_1 y =112 \tag2
$$
and an equation
$$
112 x_1 ^2 + y_1 ^2 =112 \tag3
$$
Combine formula $(1),(2),(3)$ to solve $x_0,x_1,y_1$.
the slope is the same, so
$$
\frac{-112x_1}{y_1} = 3 x_0 ^2 \tag4
$$
combine $2$ and $4$:
$$
y - 3 x_0 ^2 x = \frac{112}{y_1} \tag5
$$
so we have 
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 &= \frac{3}{2x_0}\\
y_1 &= \frac{-56}{x_0 ^3}
\end{align}
$$
substitute $3$ and obtain
$$
(x_0 ^2 -4)[4 x_0 ^4 + 7x_0 ^2 +28 ] =0
$$
the solution in real number is $x_0 = \pm 2$, so the tangent lines are
$$
y = 12x \pm 16
$$

Comment: Intersecting the dual curves $4X^3+27Y=0$ and $X^2+112Y^2-1=0$, we get $(X,Y)=(3/4,-1/16)$ and $(-3/4,1/16)$ corresponding to $3/4 x-1/16 y+1=0$ and $-3/4 x+1/16 y+1=0$ which amounts to the same two lines over the reals.

Comment: Could you help me understand how you get $y= 3 x_0 ^2 x - 2 x_0 ^3$? thank you

Comment: point $(x_0,y_0)$ at $y=x^3$, its derivative is $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x}x^3 \mid _{x=x_0}= 3x_0 ^2$. So its tangent at the point is $y-y_0 = 3x_0 ^2(x-x_0)$, together with  $y_0=x_0 ^3$, you obtain the desired one

Answer (score 0):

To find a common tangent line between the two curves means to find a line that is tangent to both curves. By means of (implicit) differentiation you can find the slope of each curve at each point, and from there you can determine the tangent line at each point.

This gives you two collections of tangent lines; the two sets of tangent lines of the two curves. Now it remains to find lines that are in both collections; these are the common tangents between the curves.

Comment: Would anyone care to explain the downvote?